# cannot see button next to search box android

Tags: android

I'm having trouble when showing a button next to the search box. I'm using an auto complete text view and i don't know if this is due to the auto complete text view. How can i fix this. Here's what i got so far:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    >

    <AutoCompleteTextView 
        android:id="@+id/autocomplete"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="text"
        />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/search_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Go"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fix this, just add the tag `android:layout_weight=1` to your AutoCompleteTextView.

This happens because android noticed you set the layout_width to fill_parent on your AutoCompleteTextView, and then it has no space for the Button left. Setting the weight to 1 means the textview will be "generous" and give as much space to any other components as they request, which in this case is limited to the width of the Button after is wrapped.

Comment: so android:layout_weight=1 is used to make "generous" views to share their space with other views?

Comment: Yes. The weight value can by anything from 0 to 1, and the default (the value you get if you don't set one explicitly) is 0. If you give 2 Views equal weight, they will try to share the space equally between them.

Comment: Well that's kind of a socialist thing views have. Thanks for the answer, it's working.

Answer (score 0):

You are filling the parent width with your AutoCompleteTextView (thus pushing the Button out of screen width). Try to change this

```
<AutoCompleteTextView 
        android:id="@+id/autocomplete"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="text"
        />
```

into this

```
<AutoCompleteTextView 
        android:id="@+id/autocomplete"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="text"
        />
```

And your Button should become visible. Here is a nice resource conserning layouts: [Android Developer | Declaring Layouts](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout.html)

Comment: Except that with approach, the AutoCompleteTextView will have almost no width and will expand as it is typed into. This probably isn't what he wants.

Comment: Yes you're right. The answer above is better solution for the problem.